# MacOS displays broken Chinese SSIDs and can't use the internet via Chinese SSIDs

Tags: macos, wifi, ssid

I'm looking for advice on how to resolve the following problem:

I'm having trouble getting a working Internet connection for a Mac OS X 10.9.5 system (configured for base language English), when I try to connect to a WiFi router that is configured with an SSID comprised Chinese/Japanese characters. Unfortunately, I don't have administrative access to the router so I can't change the WiFi router's SSID to a Latin 8-bit character set, so I can't get on the Internet.

When I try to connect with the Mac, the connection isn't rejected, but the Mac misinterprets the SSID in some code layer and the Asian character set does not get displayed property ... the characters are broken/corrupted.

In Mac OS X, I've added Chinese and Japanese character sets under `System Preference > Language & Region`, but that doesn't resolve it.

For example, when using this command :

`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I`

I get the following output

```
     agrCtlRSSI: -79
     agrExtRSSI: 0
    agrCtlNoise: -92
    agrExtNoise: 0
          state: running
        op mode: station
     lastTxRate: 24
        maxRate: 54
lastAssocStatus: 0
    802.11 auth: open
      link auth: none
          BSSID: 0:c:20:3:e7:80
           SSID: �������   <====== Not displaying the character set properly
            MCS: -1
        channel: 1
```

I have verified the SSID is saved on my computer after I make the initial contact with the WiFi router, because every time my computer is in proximity of the router, it automatically connects to it. But, oddly, when I look up on the `System Preference > Network > Wi-fi > Advanced`, I don't actually see this network saved as a preferred network (in either corrupted or in-tact Chinese characters)

The same WiFi can be connected to by my Android phone (configured for English language ), and my Windows machine (configured for Chinese language). Those clients display Chinese SSIDs correctly, and they can connect to the internet and can even make a bluetooth hotspot from my phone that the Mac can use.

Comment: First search on Apple forums and get *real* creative with Google searches for the subject and related subject. Once you confirm no workarounds, and this does sound like a real bug, you might want to file a bug: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/  I'm guessing some component in the code isn't unicode/internationalization aware, and it's a deficiency in the operating system. Just a guess. As a hacker, I would see how much of the stack I can figure out (which software components) and try to find their configuration files, but that would be a long shot. Good luck!

Comment: I've done extensive search without any good answer. I found this questions/discussions from 8 years ago: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1743940?tstart=0

Comment: If that person had actually filed a bug through Apple's bug reporter, it might have been fixed by now (might). It's important to do that when an issue hits you. Just as a service to everyone. Someone looks at the list and prioritizes the bugs and that looks like a serious one. Is it an Airport router? If it's Airport specific Apple might not be as focused as they're dropping Airport development since there are so many good routers available that work just fine now.